# What is the fastest way to make substring by searching and deleting the old substring in java?

Tags: java, string

My business logic is quite weird, but in short, I will explain here.
I have to remove the first or last occurrence of a sub string, then repeat the process. I think below code is working fine till now. Now I want to know how to optimize it because it's not performing well for large input(string length of 10000) data.

```
int count =0;
while(s.contains(substr))
{
   s= s.replaceFirst(substr,"");
   // doSomeBusinessLogic(s); 
   count++;    
}
return count;
```

examples

```
test 1 
    s = abababab
    substr = ab

    count = 4
test 2 

        s = aeerrb
        substr = er
        count =2 
        because after removing first er, the string becomes aerb,
     so remove the er again. so count is 2.
```

Edited- as per the answer it looks like matcher is better to use, however, its not producing an excepted answer.

```
   public class Solution {
        static int maxMoves(String s, String substr) {

            int count = 0;
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile(substr).matcher(s);
            while (m.find()) {
                m.appendReplacement(buf, "");
                count++;
            }
            m.appendTail(buf);
            // System.out.println(buf.toString());
            return count;

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Max Moves"+ Solution.maxMoves("aeerrb","er"));

        }



    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the input and expected output?

Comment: added the example

Comment: s.[replaceAll(substr,"")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: @stefan - the second example will not work with replace all

Comment: Have you tried with StringBuilder instead?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: The code in this answer will not handle test 2 given in the example that was later added to the question.*

With your code, inserting print statements, you get:

```
String s = "This is a test";
String substr = " ";

int count = 0;
while (s.contains(substr)) {
    s = s.replaceFirst(substr, "");
    System.out.println("doSomeBusinessLogic(\"" + s + "\")"); 
    count++;
}
System.out.println("count = " + count);
```

*Output*

```
doSomeBusinessLogic("Thisis a test")
doSomeBusinessLogic("Thisisa test")
doSomeBusinessLogic("Thisisatest")
count = 3
```

First, the parameter to `replaceFirst()` is a regex, so you need to escape the parameter, so regex special characters like `.`, `?`, `*`, `[`, `{`, ... are treated literally, not as regex patterns. To do that, call [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-).

Then, to improve the code, so you don't scan the text twice (`contains()` and `replaceFirst()`), and continue scanning from where you are, instead of from beginning, use a variant for the standard [`appendReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) loop:

```
String s = "This is a test";
String substr = " ";

int count = 0;
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(substr)).matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(buf, "");
    String ss = buf + s.substring(m.end());
    System.out.println("doSomeBusinessLogic(\"" + ss + "\")"); 
    count++;
}
// not needed here, but loop usually ends with:  m.appendTail(buf);
System.out.println("count = " + count);
```

Output is the same as before.

---

For reference, here is a more normal `appendReplacement` loop, that replaces the spaces with the `count` value:

```
int count = 0;
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(" ").matcher("This is a test");
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(buf, String.valueOf(count));
    count++;
}
m.appendTail(buf);
System.out.println(buf.toString()); // prints: This0is1a2test
```

Comment: Nice use of the `Matcher`.

Comment: Feels like looking at the String class almost :)

Comment: @Sam Read disclaimer (first paragraph of answer).

Comment: @Sam An `appendReplacement()` loop will not work for test 2. If test 2 must be handled, then this answer is not good. I wrote the answer before you added the examples. Rather than deleting the answer, I'm leaving it here, with disclaimer, in case others find this question and don't need test 2 scenarios to be handled.

Comment: glad you posted about this :)